# Redirect to/Show the 404 page in root directory when page/folder not found

Tags: php, .htaccess

Please consider the following structure of my website:

www.mydomain.com/

www.mydomain.com/index.php

www.mydomain.com/404.php

www.mydomain.com/css

www.mydomain.com/blog/

How can I show the 404.php page that exists in my root directory along with its stylinf and css, in the following cases:

1. When user tries to access a non-existing folder and/or its contents?
   Example: www.mydomain.com/nofolder
2. When user tries to access nested non-existing folders?
   Example: www.mydomain.com/nofolder1/nofolder2/nofolder3/
3. When user tries to access non-existing file nested non-existing folders?
   Example: www.mydomain.com/nofolder1/nofolder2/index.php

I already have a .htaccess file that shows the 404 page when a non-existent page is accessed in the root folder of my website. My current .htaccess file:

```
ErrorDocument 404  /404.php
```

The above code shows the CSS stripped version of my 404.php page when a non-existent folder (Example: www.mydomain.com/nofolder) is accessed. I need to show all the CSS and styling intact. For user friendliness, I think its best to retain the URL that was entered in as it is, but still show the 404 page. How can this be done?

**EDIT 1:**

I need to show this without using absolute links for the CSS. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The above code shows the CSS stripped version of my 404.php

You must use absolute path for the CSS link. Instead of this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css" />
```

use this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Doing that restores only the CSS part. I am using images to show a custom 404 message. Now all the images in the page are broken including the logo. In footer, I have bunch of images that need to show up at all times. Even they are broken. BTW, all the links are relative. Also the 404 page is sharing common includes, just as the other pages of the website are. So any change for this 404 page will automatically apply to the rest of the pages. Ho can this be fixed?

Comment: Same thing for images as for CSS: whatever you reference in `404.php` has to be absolute in order to show properly from any URL. If you're having common includes that have images or reference CSS, I would have thought they already do produce absolute URLs.

Comment: I have the following code in my inc_header.php page and if I try to include that in my index.php page to show logo, then the logo completely disappears on the index.php page (when I run this page on localhost):   <div id="logo"> <a href="index.php"><img src="/images/logo.jpg" width="250" height="149" /></a>. Any background images that I have set using the CSS, also disappear. Very surprisingly, this seems to be affecting localhost and appears correctly when I test it live on my website. This would make local development a nightmare to deal with. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: It would behave differently if you are deploying it to a subdirectory at localhost, something like `http://localhost/test/myapp/index.php`. Then the absolute addressing shifts, and you would need `/test/myapp/` prefix to everything. That would normally be achieved by having a variable with the prefix, and echoing it in front of every internal URL which is generated in multiple pages (such as the ones in your header/footer include).

Comment: I guess I have very little choice in this regard other than implementing the variable as you suggested. I will do it. Thank you so much for all your help. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Because the Error 404 page has to be able to run from any URL my 404.php simply contains

```
<?php
header("Location: http:/homepage.de");
?>
```

This way it relocates to the base URL.