# How to forbid access or redirect to another page when user enters wrong url?

Tags: php, .htaccess

Currently, I have this line in my .htaccess file: 
ErrorDocument 404 /someProject/404.php

If user enters something like this:
localhost/someProject/gehagae, then it works, it redirects him to 404.php.

But if user enters this: localhost/someProject/index.php/gehagae, it shows only the html of index page without css, images and javascript.

Same thing happens with every page, so how do you redirect it to 404.php?

Comment: try to write the full path of your ``404 page`` for example
``ErrorDocument 404 http://YOURURL``

Answer (score 0):

try to write the full path of your **404 page**

for example `ErrorDocument 404 http://YOURURL`

and make sure in your `CSS` files you write the **absolute** path not the **relative**
for example, if you write it like this

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
```

change it to this one

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style.css" />``
```

Comment: When I write full path to 404, nothing happens, it even stops redirecting to 404.php. As for css, same thing as before

Comment: check this answer to it may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8783144/redirect-to-show-the-404-page-in-root-directory-when-page-folder-not-found?rq=1

Comment: hmm, but I dont need css to show up. I just need it to redirect to my 404 :/